# What is the limiting distribution of loss portfolio?

Tags: distribution, vasicek

I am working through this [paper](http://mx.nthu.edu.tw/~jtyang/Teaching/Risk_management/Papers/Models/Probability%20of%20Loss%20on%20Loan%20Portfolio.pdf) on Vasicek's portfolio loss distribution.

On page 3 he mentions that by the law of large numbers,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor nx \rfloor} \binom{n}{k}s^k(1-s)^{n-k}  = 1_{\{x \ge s \}}$$ where $s \in (0,1)$,

Here $x$ is some real number, $k$ is an integer and $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient.

but I can't quite work out why this is the case.

I have tried some sort of binomial distribution argument but haven't been very successful!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what the symbol mean in your formula. Also please rephrase the tile as a question.

Comment: It's better, but we still can't really understand what the meaning is. Just in a few words you could explain what the paper is about and what that formula is supposed to represent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{split}\sum_{k=0}^{[nx]}\binom{n}{k}s^k(1-s)^{n-k}& =\sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb{1}_{k\leq [nx]} \binom{n}{k}s^k(1-s)^{n-k} \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb{1}_{k\leq nx} \binom{n}{k}s^k(1-s)^{n-k} \\ 
& = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{B}(n,s)\leq nx)\\
& = \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\mathcal{B}(n,x)}{n}\leq x\right)\end{split}$$

where $\mathcal{B}(n,s)$ is a binomial of parameters $(n,s)$

using the law of large number you get $\frac{\mathcal{B}(n,s)}{n}\to_{n\to\infty} s$ and you can conclude.